# Numpy: calculate based on previous element?

Tags: python, numpy

Say that I have array `x` and `y`:

```
x = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])  # actual content is the a result of another calculation step
```

There's a formula for `y`, and each element is based on the previous element, let `i` denote the index of `y`, each element is:

```
y[i] = y[i-1] * 2 + x[i]
```

When calculating the first element, let `y[i-1] = 50`. In other words, `y` should be:

```
[101, 204, 411, 826, 1657, 3320, 6647, 13302, 26613, 53236]
```

How do I calculate `y` with numpy?

Comment: What would be the starting value of `y`, i.e. `y[0]`?

Comment: Well, there's an artificial start value of 50.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you wrote?

Comment: @moose, it's just the pseudo code, not numpy.

Comment: This is a non-homogeneous linear recurrence equation. Have you considered finding the analytic solution first, then seeing if it could be efficiently coded?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lets build a few of the items in your sequence:

```
y[0] = 2*y[-1] + x[0]
y[1] = 2*y[0] + x[1] = 4*y[-1] + 2*x[0] + x[1]
y[2] = 2*y[1] + x[2] = 8*y[-1] + 4*x[0] + 2*x[1] + x[2]
...
y[n] = 2**(n+1)*y[-1] + 2**n*x[0] + 2**(n-1)*x[1] + ... + x[n]
```

It may not be immediately obvious, but you can build the above sequence with numpy doing something like:

```
n = len(x)
y_1 = 50
pot = 2**np.arange(n-1, -1, -1)
y = np.cumsum(pot * x) / pot + y_1 * 2**np.arange(1, n+1)
>>> y
array([  101,   204,   411,   826,  1657,  3320,  6647, 13302, 26613, 53236])
```

The down side to this type of solutions is that they are not very general: a small change in your problem may render the whole approach useless. But whenever you can solve a problem with a little algebra, it is almost certainly going to beat any algorithmic approach by a far margin.

Comment: `numpy.cumsum()` is much faster than using a `for` loop, ~8x faster for my test application.

Answer (score 6):

If you need a recursive computation, if your `y[i]` should depend on the computed `y[i-1]` from the same run, then there seems to be no built-in solution in numpy, and you will need to compute it using a simple `for` loop:

```
y = np.empty(x.size)
last = 50
for i in range(x.size):
    y[i] = last = last * 2 + x[i]
```

See this question: [Is a "for" loop necessary if elements of the a numpy vector are dependant upon the previous element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407984/is-a-for-loop-necessary-if-elements-of-the-a-numpy-vector-are-dependant-upon-t)

Otherwise, you can implement your formula in one line using numpy:

```
y = np.concatenate(([50], y[:-1])) * 2 + x
```

Explanation:

```
y[:-1]
```

Creates a `N-1`-sized array: `y_0, y_1, ... y_N-1`.

```
np.concatenate(([50], y[:-1]))
```

Creates a `N`-sized array with the first element your starting value 50.  So this expression basically is your `y[i-1]`.

Then you can do the math element-wise using numpy array arithmetics.

Comment: Nice! And then change the first element of `y`.

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `[101, 204, 411, 826, 1657, 3320, 6647, 13302, 26613, 53236]`? Mismatch with second element I guess? Should be 204 and not 102

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle the recurrence properly. It looks like it's designed to construct a whole new `y` array from an old `y` and `x`, while the desired behavior seems to be for the given relationship to hold within a single `y` array; the desired result would be a fixed point of this solution.

Comment: OK, I think I misunderstood the requirements then. If the OP wants a recursive formula, this answer won't work for him. (There was no example result when I wrote this answer)

Comment: Indeed what I wanted is recursive, I didn't realize that and I expect numpy to be capable of this through some magic slicing. Thank you for the explanation. I'll stay with the for loop.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the fastest and most concise way is to use [scipy.signal.lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html), which implements exactly the kind of recursive relationship you described:

```
from scipy.signal import lfilter
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

b = [1., 0.]
a = [1., -2.]
zi = np.array([2*50])  # initial condition
y, _ = lfilter(b, a, x, zi=zi)
```

Result will be `np.float64`, but you can cast to e.g. `np.int32` if that's what you need:

```
>>> y.astype(np.int32)
array([  101,   204,   411,   826,  1657,  3320,  6647, 13302, 26613, 53236])
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how to do it with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10 ])
y = np.array([ 50 ])
for i in np.arange(len(x)):
    y = np.append(
                  y,
                  ( y[-1] * 2 + x[i] )
                  )
y = y[1:]

print(y)
```

Comment: never use for loops, when it comes to performance in python