# Updating a python array without loops?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a recursive relation, that I want to update without using loops for speed.

For example

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,0,0,0,0])
x[1:]=(1+x[0:len(x)-1])**2.
```

This returns `[1,4,1,1,1]` for `x`, but I want `[1,4,25,676,458329]`.  I know this can be done with a loop, but I'm really trying to avoid loops.

For example,

```
for i in range(1,len(x)):
    x[i]=(1+x[i-1])**2.
```

will return `[1,4,25,676,458329]`

Comment: Are you looking for `x[1:]=x[0]`?

Comment: I think you need to describe your question in a more specific way. Hope then we can help you better.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then explain your question in more detail with more examples of inputs and the desired outputs.

Comment: I'm looking for x[1]=x[0], and then x[2]=x[1] using this updated value of x[1].  Maybe the example I've put here is too simple, I'm trying to do this for a Runge-Kutta type scheme

Comment: it looks like you want to apply an operation across the array without an explicit loop

Comment: Yes, exactly.  But from the way slicing appears to work, it uses the old version of the array, and doesn't use the new value as it's updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to vectorize recursive calculation of a NumPy array where each element depends on the previous one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407984/is-it-possible-to-vectorize-recursive-calculation-of-a-numpy-array-where-each-el)

Comment: It is, thank you, I hadn't been able to find that!

Comment: In your example, the RHS is evaluated (as a whole), and then assigned to the LHS.  The 'vectorization' is parallel, not serial.  When you ask about alternatives to doing things with a loop it's good idea to provide a working example using the loop.  It makes it a lot easier to verify our answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to vectorize recursive calculation of a NumPy array where each element depends on the previous one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407984/is-it-possible-to-vectorize-recursive-calculation-of-a-numpy-array-where-each-el)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.array([1,0,0,0,0])
>>> x[1:]=1
>>> x
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm not clear.  I have x[1] dependent on x[0], x[2] dependent on x[1], and so on and so forth.  It's not that I want an array of ones, I want this dependency without a loop.

Comment: Can you please use the different example set like a more diverse one? It doesn't seem perfect one.

Answer (score 1):

[NumPy has a list of operations that work on arrays so you don't have to use an explicit for-loop to modify/update the array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.math.html#arithmetic-operations).

One of them is [add](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html#numpy.add) which can add one array with another and you can use concatenate to operate on specific parts of the array:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
head = x[:1] # => [1]
tail = x[1:] # => [0, 0, 0, 0]
tail_values = np.full_like(tail, 1) # => [1, 1, 1, 1]
tail_plus_one = np.add(tail, tail_values) # => [0, 0, 0, 0] + [1, 1, 1, 1]
np.concatenate(head, tail_plus_one) # => [1] + [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

NumPy has [a section in their user guide on iterating and modifying arrays and how to make it an efficient operation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values).

Comment: I've updated my question to a more specific example, as it appears I was too vague before in what I was trying to do.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is what you are trying to do:

```
In [30]: x = np.array([1,0,0,0,0])                                                                              
In [31]: for i in range(1,len(x)): 
    ...:     x[i] = (1+x[i-1])**2 
    ...:                                                                                                        
In [32]: x                                                                                                      
Out[32]: array([     1,      4,     25,    676, 458329])
```

Many of the `ufunc` implement an `accumulate` method

```
In [33]: np.add.accumulate(np.arange(5))                                                                        
Out[33]: array([ 0,  1,  3,  6, 10])
In [34]: np.multiply.accumulate(np.arange(1,6))                                                                 
Out[34]: array([  1,   2,   6,  24, 120])
```

They iterate as above, but do so in compiled code. But, in general, you can't run your own Python function with the same speed.