# How to speed up calculations involving previous row and multi-row pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to make a calculation on multiple rows for every row in a dataframe.

My current solution takes so much time when I run 2971000 rows. it almost takes more than 2hours.

So, I want know other solutions to speed up a function

my data looks like this for example.

```
                        sig1    sig2   sig3   sig4  sig_p   sig_t
20210114 05:52:02.00     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   11.5    -3.5
20210114 05:52:02.01     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   11.6    -3.5
20210114 05:52:02.02     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   11.5    -3.5
20210114 05:52:02.03     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   11.6    -3.5
20210114 05:52:02.04     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   11.7    -3.5
...                      ...    ...    ...    ...   ...     ...
20210114 22:38:59.85     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0     -0.5
20210114 22:38:59.86     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0     -0.5
20210114 22:38:59.87     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0     -0.5
20210114 22:38:59.88     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0     -0.5
20210114 22:38:59.89     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0     -0.5
```

I have a function which loops through and calculates value for `newcol` based on `sig1`, `sig_p`, `sig_t`,`previous newcol`. the function runs repeat for `sig1`, `sig2`, `sig3`, `sig4`.

I'll show you the code I currently have, but it's too slow.

```
parameter.py

from typing import NamedTuple
class Param(NamedTuple):
    RATIO                     : float
    D                         : float
    T                         : float
    M                         : float
    S                         : float
    W                         : float
    DYNAMIC                   : float
    
    T_CONST                   : float
    P_CONST                   : float
    
    L_COEF                    : float
    O_COEF                    : float
    
    
    @property
    def A(self):
        return (self.D**2)*math.pi
    @property
    def FACTOR(self):
        return self.S / self.A

Param1 = Param(
    RATIO                     = 0.74,
    
    D                         = 172e-3,
    T                         = 23e-3,
    M                         = 6,
    
    S                         = 53.7e-4,#4232.5e-6,
    W                         = 0.805,
    DYNAMIC                   = 0.3150,
    
    T_CONST                   = 2, #4,
    P_CONST                   = 0.2,#3,
    
    
    L_COEF                    = 0.8,#4,
    O_COEF                    = 2.5
)

rear = Param(
    RATIO                     = 0.26,
    
    D                         = 204e-3,
    T                         = 10e-3,
    M                         = 4,
    
    S                         = 26.8e-4,
    W                         = 0.38,
    
    DYNAMIC                   = 0.3150,
        
    T_CONST                   = 1.8,
    P_CONST                   = 0.2,
    
    L_COEF                    = 0.2,
    O_COEF                    = 1.8
)
```

```
test.py

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


TIME_STAMP = 0.1
SPEC = 449
SPECIFIC = 935

EMISSIVITY                      = 0.7
ABSORBTIVITY                    = 0.3

DYNAMIC_SPEED = 12

COEFFICIENT = 0.9506173967164384

input_KV = [-75, -50, -25, -15, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 60,
                        80, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 300, 412, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100]

viscosity_value = [7.4, 9.22, 11.18, 12.01, 12.43, 12.85, 13.28, 13.72, 14.16, 14.61, 15.06, 15.52, 15.98, 16.92, 17.88, 18.86, 20.88,
               22.97, 25.69, 28.51, 31.44, 34.47, 37.6, 47.54, 63.82, 77.72, 94.62, 112.6, 131.7, 151.7, 172.7, 194.6]
               
input_ka = [-190, -150, -100, -75, -50, -25, -15, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40,
                     50, 60, 80, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 300, 412, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100]

conductivity_value = [7.82, 11.69, 16.2, 18.34, 20.41, 22.41, 23.2, 23.59, 23.97, 24.36, 24.74, 25.12, 25.5, 25.87, 26.24, 26.62,
                    27.35, 28.08, 28.8, 30.23, 31.62, 33.33, 35, 36.64, 38.25, 39.83, 44.41, 50.92, 55.79, 61.14, 66.32, 71.35, 76.26, 81.08, 85.83] 

def viscosity(input):
    fq = interp1d(input_KV,
                  viscosity_value, kind='quadratic')
    return (fq(input)*10e-6)

def conductivity(input):
    fq = interp1d(input_ka,
                  conductivity_value, kind='quadratic')
    return (fq(input)*10e-3)                              
    
def calculation(Param, sig, sig_p, sig_t):
    new_col1 = np.empty(len(sig_p))
    new_col1[0] = sig_t[0]

    my_goal = np.empty(len(sig_p))
    my_goal[0] = sig_t[0]
            
      
    calc1 = COEFFICIENT * Param.RATIO * sig_p * sig /2

    for n in range(1, len(sig_p)):
        calc2 = EMISSIVITY * Param.A * (new_col1[n-1]**4 - sig_t[n]**4)
        
        Ka = conductivity(sig_t[n])
        if sig[n] == 0:
            h = Param.O_COEF
        else :
            KV = viscosity(sig_t[n])
            
            if sig[n] < DYNAMIC_SPEED:
                h = (0.7*(sig[n]/KV)**0.4) * Ka + Param.O_COEF
            else :
                h = (0.04*(sig[n])/KV**0.8) * Ka + Param.L_COEF
            
        calc3 = h * Param.A * (new_col1[n-1] - sig_t[n])
        calc4 = Ka *Param.A * (new_col1[n-1] - sig_t[n]) / Param.T

        a1 = (calc1[n] - (calc2 + calc3 + calc4)) / (SPEC * Param.M)
        new_col1[n] = new_col1[n-1] + a1 * TIME_STAMP
        
        if sig_p[n] == 0 :
            val1 = ABSORBTIVITY * Param.FACTOR * calc2
        elif (sig_p[n] > 0) & (sig_p[n] <= 20):
            val1 = ABSORBTIVITY * Param.FACTOR * calc2* (20-sig_p[n])/20 + ((1-COEFFICIENT) * calc1[n] / (4)) * sig_p[n] / 20
        else:
            val1 = (1-COEFFICIENT) * calc1[n] / 4
            
        if sig[n] == 0:
            val2 = Param.T_CONST
        else:
            h_bar = Param.P_CONST * (sig[n] *Param.DYNAMIC)**0.8
            val2 = h_bar * Param.S * (my_goal[n-1] - sig_t[n])
            
        a2 = (val1 - (val2)) / (SPECIFIC * Param.W)
        my_goal[n] = my_goal[n-1] + a2 * TIME_STAMP
        if my_goal[n] < sig_t[0] : my_goal[n] = sig_t[0]
            
    return my_goal
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)

df['newcol1'] = calculation(Param1, df['sig1'].values, df[sig_p].values, df['sig_t'].values)
df['newcol2'] = calculation(Param1, df['sig2'].values, df[sig_p].values, df['sig_t'].values)
df['newcol3'] = calculation(Param2, df['sig3'].values, df[sig_p].values, df['sig_t'].values)
df['newcol4'] = calculation(Param2, df['sig4'].values, df[sig_p].values, df['sig_t'].values)
```

I now need to apply this function to several million rows and it's impossibly slow so I'm trying to figure out the best way to speed it up. I've heard that Cython can increase the speed of functions but I have no experience with it (and I'm new to both pandas and python).

My question is if there is anyway to enhance or speed up this computation method.

I'm run this python code on AWS(sagemaker>notebook instance, jupyter) and my computer OS is window.

Comment: param is class NamedTuple.

Comment: dataframe performs the best with vectorized operation. iteration is usually not recommended. also, what'd fun1, fun2... do? any sample param you can provide as well?

Comment: Sara, can you in simple words explain what you want to get done. You have a very complex function written up. It would be best if we can understand what you want to get done so we can use alternate solutions. Like Simon said, it would be best to use vectorized operations.

Comment: The functions are base on physics formulas, so it's difficult to explain in simple words. What I want to get done is `newcol` values. `newcol` is an estimation value involving previous row and current rows. @JoeFerndz

Comment: I have uploaded all the code including param to get the `newcol` value. @Simon

Comment: @sara, glance over your long code. found lots of typo. The Param doesn't match to the one in fun(). And i can't see anything that can exit the while loop inside fun().

Comment: basically, to improve the performance. Especially for dataframe, you should avoid looping / iteration and make use of dataframe function as long as it's possible.

Comment: @Simon I corrected the typo in my code. I try to modified my code like this.
`def calculation(Param, df):`
`calc2 = EMISSIVITY * Param.A * (df['new_col1'].shift(1)**4 - df['sig_t']**4)`

Comment: First, I was only going to get the value of new_col1 like calc2. But it didn't work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iteration is easy to code but slow for dataframe. Here is a hint to your solution. You need to vectorize the code inside the while loop `while n < len(sig_p):`.
For example, previously your code:

```
def fun(Param, sig_p, sig, sig_t):
    tempvalue =   np.empty(sig_p.shape)
    tempvalue[0] = sig_t[0]
    newcol = np.empty(sig_p.shape)
    newcol[0] = sig_t[0]

    n = 1
    while n < len(sig_p):
        # calc1 = fun1()
        calc1 = Param.COEF * (sig_p[n]) * Param.NO * Param.EFF # fun1()

        # calc2 = fun2()
        if sig[n] > Param.THRESHOLD:
            calc2 = 0
        else:
            calc2 = Param.EMISSIVITY * Param.CONSTANT * (tempvalue[n-1]**4 - sig_t[n]**4)

        # calc3
        # calc4
        # ......

df['newcol1'] = fun(param1, df['sig_p'].values, df['sig1'].values, df['sig_t'].values)
```

To eliminate the while loop, the fun1() and fun2 can be rewritten like this:

```
def fun(Param, df, sigTag):
    # df['calc1'] = vectorized fun1()
    df['calc1'] = Param.COEF * df['sig_p'] * Param.NO * Param.EFF  

    # df['calc2'] = vectorized fun2()
    df['calc2'] = Param.EMISSIVITY * Param.CONSTANT * (df['sig_t'].shift(1)**4 - df['sig_t']**4)
    df.loc[df[sigTag] > Param.THRESHOLD, 'calc2'] = 0

    # df['calc3'] = vectorized fun3()
    # df['calc4'] = vectorized fun4()
    # ......
    
df['newcol1'] = fun(param1, df, 'sig1')
```

you might also want to input the dataframe to the fun() rather than in separated ndarray(s).

This approach'd greatly enhance the performance. You might want to do some research on how to vectorize the calculation.

Comment: my function is `df['calc2'] = Param.EMISSIVITY * Param.CONSTANT * (df['new_col'].shift(1)**4 - df['sig_t']**4)`

Comment: Is it possible to vectorize dataframe when i wnat to get recursive values?

Comment: i suggest you break the calculations into several columns, maybe try it out in an excel first. it will be easier to search for the answer or you might probably want to ask a new question about dataframe vertorization for some of your breakdown issue.

Comment: I searched about my issue. And I found this link. [link](http://https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407984/is-it-possible-to-vectorize-recursive-calculation-of-a-numpy-array-where-each-el) According to the answer to this link, **It is possible to vectorize operations on vectors as long as the calculation is not recursive. Because a recursive operation depends on the previously calculated value it is not possible to parallel process the operation. This does therefore not work**.So, I can't understand your answer. If it is possible to the vectorization how can I possibly about my issue?

Comment: The OP said the recursive calculation was too slow, so i suggest you to vertorize your formula. This answer won't be helpful if you can't come up with a the formula or intended to use recursive calculation. Again, please try with excel 1st and ask a new question with excel result. it would be easier to breakdown the issue(maybe how to formulate a single column) and get the answer with limited lines of code.