# maximum restart when condition occurs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How I can restart fmax counting when a condition occurs?
I got two numpy arrays, I call `np.fmax.accumulate` on the first, but when it touches the second array value at the same index, it should turns to the first array value at the same index, and then reset and restart maximum accumulating.
Example:

```
array2 = np.array([4,4,4,3,5,2,1])
array1 = np.array([1,2,3,2,4,1,0.5])
max = np.fmax.accumulate(array1)

                   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
array2             4   4   4   3   5   2   1
array1             1   2   3   2   4   1  0.5   
max                1   2   3   3   4   4   4

expected output    1   2   3   2   4   1  0.5
                               ^       ^   ^
```

Can I do this using JUST numpy or at least NO LOOPS?

Comment: What do you mean by "when it touches the second array value"? Can you express that in logical terms?

Comment: I mean when `expected output >= array2` @bill

Comment: Good question. I have previously wondered if it's possible to use np.accumulate with a function having more than one input variable but based on the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407984/is-it-possible-to-vectorize-recursive-calculation-of-a-numpy-array-where-each-el/62736143#62736143) I concluded it isn't. However, in your case `array2` is pre-computed so I wonder if there is a way to pass the whole array into a custom [ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html) and then use `accumulate` on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
output = np.where(max < array2, max, array1)
[1.  2.  3.  2.  4.  1.  0.5]
```

Comment: I don't think this resets and restarts the maximum accumulating.

Comment: Why shouldnt work in general? for example in presence of nans? @MichaelSzczesny

Comment: For `array2 = np.array([4,4,4,3,5,2,5])` the reset isn't working as expected.

Comment: I think that the only method for doing this is by for loop, do not ask me why, but it seems to work only with these arrays values, if you change them, accumulation wont reset. (even if array1 is always smaller than array2)